# tensorflow recommeders item item recommender

Tags: tensorflow, recommender-system

I am trying to create an item-item recommender using tensorflow recommenders (TFRS).

I have successfully created a user-item recommender using TFRS using the code at this link as a template: [TFRS retrieval](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval)

There is an explanation at the bottom of the page of that link that describes how to implement an item-item architecture: '*Item-to-item recommendation
In this model, we created a user-movie model. Training models like this would follow the same pattern as shown in this tutorial, but with different training data. Here, we had a user and a movie tower, and used (user, movie) pairs to train them. In an item-to-item model, we would have two item towers (for the query and candidate item), and train the model using (query item, candidate item) pairs.*'
'
We have a total of about 7000 unique user_id values and 100000 unique domain (purchases) values. The domain values will be predicted as purchases for the user_id. I will only be using user and item features. No rating or other features.

each user_id corresponds to a unique user. each unique company number can exist in multiple rows with different domain values or repeated domain values. A row consists of a user and their respective purchase.

I have the following attempt at the model:

```
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
import mlflow
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RankingMetrics
import os
import cloudpickle
import sys
import shutil



train_data = pd.read_csv('/path/to/train_data.csv', index_col=0)
train = train_data[[user_col, item_col]]
train = train.dropna()

test_data = pd.read_csv('/path/to/test_data.csv', index_col=0)
test = test_data[[user_col, item_col]]
test = test.dropna()

train_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(train))
test_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(test))
df_tf = train_tf.concatenate(test_tf)

data = pd.concat([train, test])

# Features of all the available domains.
domains = data[[item_col]].drop_duplicates()
domains_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(domains))

user_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
user_ids_vocabulary.adapt(df_tf.map(lambda x: tf.strings.as_string(x[user_col])))

domain_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
domain_vocabulary.adapt(data[item_col].apply(str).values)

df_tf = df_tf.map(lambda x: {
    "query_domain": tf.cast(domain_vocabulary(tf.strings.as_string(x[item_col])), tf.int64),
    "candidate_domain": tf.cast(domain_vocabulary(tf.strings.as_string(x[item_col])), tf.int64),
    "company_number__c": tf.strings.as_string(x[user_col])
})

query_item_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=user_ids_vocabulary.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, input_shape=()),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(user_ids_vocabulary.get_vocabulary()) + 1, 32)
])

candidate_item_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=domain_vocabulary.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, input_shape=()),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(domain_vocabulary.get_vocabulary()) + 1, 32)
])

task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(candidates=domains_tf.batch(1000).map(lambda x: candidate_item_model(tf.expand_dims(tf.strings.as_string(x[item_col]), -1)))))

class ItemItemModel(tfrs.Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        query_item_model: tf.keras.Model,
        candidate_item_model: tf.keras.Model,
        task: tfrs.tasks.Retrieval):
        super().__init__()

        self.query_item_model = query_item_model
        self.candidate_item_model = candidate_item_model
        self.task = task

    def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
        query_item_embeddings = self.query_item_model(features["query_domain"])
        candidate_item_embeddings = self.candidate_item_model(features["candidate_domain"])

        return self.task(query_item_embeddings, candidate_item_embeddings)

model = ItemItemModel(query_item_model, candidate_item_model, task)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.1))

model.fit(df_tf.batch(4096), epochs=10)

index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.query_item_model)
index.index_from_dataset(
  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(domains)).batch(1000).map(
      lambda x: (x[item_col], model.candidate_item_model(x[item_col]))
  )
)

# Generating recommendations
user_id = "12345"
_, titles = index(tf.constant([user_id]))
recommended_domain_ids = [domain_vocabulary.get_vocabulary()[x] for x in titles[0].numpy()]

# Print the top 10 recommended domains for the user
print("Top 10 recommended domains for user:", user_id)
print(recommended_domain_ids[:10])
```

I seem to be chasing around type errors.

Is there an obvious problem with this model that I am missing?

An example of the data would resemble this dataframe

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate user_id and item_id arrays
user_id = np.repeat(np.arange(100), 100)
item_id = np.tile(np.arange(200), 50)

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': user_id, 'item_id': item_id})

# shuffle the items within each group of user_id
df = df.groupby('user_id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))

# reset the index of the dataframe
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```
````